# Merging scrlttr2 and komacv layout

Tags: scrlttr2

I want to merge a `scrlttr2` and a `komacv`.

I want the headers from `komacv` to be congruent with those of `scrlttr2`. So on page 1 of `komacv` there should be the blue line (with same length as in scrlttr2 page 1) and the name and address stuff.

Page 2 of the `komacv` should accordingly have the header of page 2 of `scrlttr2` (with the corresponding length on page 2).

The photo from `komacv` needs to stay on the left side. It should align with the left side of the blue boxes (or with the left end of the header).

I need your help! Thanks!

Update: Deleted source code and graphics, because they are not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`komacv` is based on the KOMA-Script class `scrartcl`. So it is possible to use the relatively new KOMA-Script package `scrletter` to set the letter and the cv in one document.

Additional I would use `scrlayer` to define a new page style for the first pages of both the letter and the cv.

But `komacv` still loads `scrpage2` and this package can not be used together with `scrlayer-scrpage`. So first of all

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}]{scrpage2}
```

ensures that `komacv` does not load `scrpage2`.

Then we can the define a new layer using the `letter` pseudolength

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  area={\useplength{toaddrhpos}}{\useplength{firstheadvpos}}%
       {\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}{3cm},
  contents={\parbox[t]{\layerwidth}{\raggedleft
    \usekomavar{fromname}\strut\\[-6pt]
    \textcolor{myblue}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}}}
]{firsthead}
```

and declare a new page style using this layer

```
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firsthead}
```

To align the photo you can insert this directly or redefine  `maketitle`

```
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  %\hspace*{\dimexpr-.5\paperwidth+.5\textwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}% to align with the headsepline
  \fcolorbox{mycolor}{white}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{jeyre}}%
}
```

[image]

[image]

or alternatively

[image]

Code:

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}]{scrpage2}

\documentclass[style=classic]{komacv}
\hypersetup{hypertexnames=false}

\usepackage{scrletter}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Jane Eyre}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ferndean House\\Ferndean Village}
\setkomavar{subject}{Writing a letter}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=2pt,plainheadsepline,draft=false}
\setkomafont{headsepline}{\color{mycolor}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page~\thepage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  area={\useplength{toaddrhpos}}{\useplength{firstheadvpos}}%
       {\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}{3cm},
  contents={\parbox[t]{\layerwidth}{\raggedleft
    \usekomavar{fromname}\strut\\[-6pt]
    \textcolor{myblue}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}}}
]{firsthead}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firsthead}

\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr-.5\paperwidth+.5\textwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}%
  \fcolorbox{mycolor}{white}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{jeyre}}%
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
        Ernst Hemingway\\
        Main street\\
        2300 PAMPLONA%
}
\opening{}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}

Bulls are nice, but the last general meeting was about one year ago.
I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.

\pagebreak

I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.
\closing{Thank you}
\end{letter}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}
\cvitem{Nationality}{British}
\cvitem{Civil Status}{Married, two children}
...
\clearpage
\section{All Elements}
\subsection{cvitem}
\cvitem{header}{cvitem text
  \begin{compactenum}
    \item compactenum item one
    \item compactenum item two
  \end{compactenum}
}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** (because of a comment)

If the bars in cv should be 4pt height you have to redefine `\@cvbarsection` to

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cvbarsection[1]{%
  \origsection*{
    \phantomsection{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \cvitem[0pt]{%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{\color{@secbarcolor}%
        \rule{\@hintscolwidth}{4pt}}% <- defines the bar
    }{\sectionstyle{#1}}
  }
}
\makeatother
```

But note this is only a small change of the original `komacv` code. The original `komacv` code already breaks some of the possibilities of the current KOMA-Script version.

Result with `roboto` font:

[image]

Code:

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading[\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}]{scrpage2}

\documentclass[style=classic]{komacv}
\hypersetup{hypertexnames=false}

\usepackage{scrletter}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Jane Eyre}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Ferndean House\\Ferndean Village}
\setkomavar{subject}{Writing a letter}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{}

\KOMAoptions{headsepline=2pt,plainheadsepline,draft=false}
\setkomafont{headsepline}{\color{mycolor}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page~\thepage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  area={\useplength{toaddrhpos}}{\useplength{firstheadvpos}}%
       {\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}{3cm},
  contents={\parbox[t]{\layerwidth}{\raggedleft
    \usekomavar{fromname}\strut\\[-6pt]
    \textcolor{myblue}{\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}}}
]{firsthead}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{firstpage}{firsthead}

\renewcommand\maketitle{%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr-.5\paperwidth+.5\textwidth+\useplength{toaddrhpos}\relax}%
  \fcolorbox{mycolor}{white}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{jeyre}}%
}
\usepackage{roboto}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cvbarsection[1]{%
  \origsection*{
    \phantomsection{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \cvitem[0pt]{%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{\color{@secbarcolor}%
        \rule{\@hintscolwidth}{4pt}}%
    }{\sectionstyle{#1}}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
        Ernst Hemingway\\
        Main street\\
        2300 PAMPLONA%
}
\opening{}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}

Bulls are nice, but the last general meeting was about one year ago.
I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.

\pagebreak

I want to remind you, that the constitution of our
club advises you to make a general meeting every
six month. Because of this I expect the executive
board to detain such a meeting immediately.
\closing{Thank you}
\end{letter}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\pagestyle{plain.scrheadings}
\raggedbottom
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\maketitle

\section{Personal Information}
\cvitem{Date of birth}{February 15, 1828}
\cvitem{Nationality}{British}
\cvitem{Civil Status}{Married, two children}
...
\clearpage
\section{All Elements}
\subsection{cvitem}
\cvitem{header}{cvitem text
  \begin{compactenum}
    \item compactenum item one
    \item compactenum item two
  \end{compactenum}
}
\end{document}
```

Use the opitional argument of `\rule` if you want to change the vertical position of the bars.

---

**Second update**

`komacv` does some hacks witch break some of the possibilities of the current KOMA versions. Especially `\RecdeclareSectionCommand` does not work. Also the commands `\beforesecvspace` etc. seems to have no effect. There is a information in the `komacv` documentation:

> Note that the section and subsection definition of komacv needs
>   improvement, so the setting of these lengths may not produce the
>   desired result and the result may change in future versions.

As a workaround you can insert `\vspace*{...}` in the redefinition of `\@cvbarsection` and `\@cvbarsubsection` but note this are only hacks:

```
\usepackage{roboto}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cvbarsection[1]{%
  \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}% <- 
  \origsection*{
    \phantomsection{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
    \cvitem[0pt]{%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{\color{@secbarcolor}%
        \rule{\@hintscolwidth}{4pt}}%
    }{\sectionstyle{#1}}
  }
}
\renewcommand\@cvbarsubsection[1]{%
  \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}% <- 
  \origsubsection*{
    \cvitem[0pt]{}{\subsectionstyle{#1}}
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way that I can change the spacing between the ´cv section´ elements? I tried to understand and use the explanation in ´komacv´ manual. But it did not work. Also I use ´roboto´ font, that makes the blue bars in the ´komacv´ much heigher. I wish they would be 4pt height and centered or bottom aligned with the textline. PS: How did you make that doublepage screenshot?

Comment: BTW: I wish I could give 5 stars! Your answer is amazing and well explained.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Doublepage screenshot: in the viewer (Sumatra, Adobe Reader, ...) menu I can choose the doublepage view and then I use "Snipping Tool" that is provided by Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also mention how to adjust the vertical spacings between the `cv section` elements and also the `cv subsection` elements?

Comment: I have added a workaround. But if there are more questions ask a new question please. I myself do not use `komacv` and the `komacv` code breaks some of the possibilities of the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: Dont know, if it useful if I open a new topic for this... how can I change the font color of the header on page 2 of the letter, not the cv. For cv this works: `\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\textcolor{myblue}{Seite~\thepage}}`

Comment: You could use `\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{myblue}}` and  `\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Seite~\thepage}`. If you need more explanations then ask a new question.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error message when trying to apply your second update´! LaTeX Error: \@cvbarsection undefined.´What can I do ?

Comment: Second I would love to be able to shape the thickness of the blue rectangles and please can you give me a hint how to adjust the image with the first line of the adress on the right hand side (so it sits directly beneath the blue header line)? Thank you very much!